# how to use publishDir to publish result to different places in nextflow

Tags: nextflow

```
process A {
...
output:
path("*linkedfrag"), emit: lf
path("*hapblock"), emit: hb

publishDir ???
...
}
```

Is there a way to publish lf to ${params.outdir}/lf/ and hb to ${params.outdir}/hb/ ?
I dont want to emit lf as "lf/*linkedfrag" etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way would be to actually specify more than one [publishDir](https://www.nextflow.io/docs/latest/process.html#publishdir) directive. This approach provides increased flexibility by giving you the option to specify a different set of rules for each directive. To publish your output files to different target directories, you could just use the `pattern` parameter to select the files to publish from the overall set of output files:

```
process A {

    publishDir "${params.outdir}/lf", pattern: "*linkedfrag"
    publishDir "${params.outdir}/hb", pattern: "*hapblock"

    ...
}
```

Another way would be to use the `saveAs` parameter to set the required path. This example uses a [ternary operator](https://groovy-lang.org/operators.html#_ternary_operator), but you could also use an if/else-if/else block<sup>[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76063086/751863)</sup>:

```
process A {

    publishDir (
        path: params.outdir,
        saveAs: { fn ->
            fn.endsWith('linkedfrag') ? "lf/${fn}" :
            fn.endsWith('hapblock') ? "hb/${fn}" :
            fn
        }
    )

    ...
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. what if I want to save the output to both lf and hb subdirectories?

Comment: @CaiBian I think the only way would be to use multiple `publishDir` directives, like in the first example. Just remove the `pattern` parameter to publish all of the (declared) files to these sub-directories.